# Plot a multi-line text box in R

Tags: r

I am creating a multi-plot layout illustration using R, and it would be convenient to be able to create a multi-line text box in one of the plots.

I am familiar with using Sweave to combine images, text, and R code, however for various reasons I need this to be a single page plot produced in R.  Thus the need to plot a text box rather than use Latex mark-up.

Is there a function in an existing package that can do this?  Failing that, can anyone suggest a simple approach for handling this?

Consider this situation:

```
## Specify the dimensions of the plot
## that we require
win.graph(8,4)

## Two panel layout
layout(matrix(1:2, 1, 2))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

## Left panel shows picture
plot(rep(1:10, each=10), rep(1:10, times=10), 
col=rainbow(100), pch=20, cex=5)


## Right panel discusses the data
plot.default(c(0,100), c(0,100), type="n", axes=FALSE,
ylab="", xlab="")

text(20, 30, "It would be great if this text box\n
could handle word wrap, and ideally given the size\n
of the font (i.e. the cex parameter) and the area\n
of the plot it should be able to do this dynamically,\n
without requiring the newline characters I am\n
manually inserting.  Ability to control the line\n
height would also be nice.\n
Am I dreaming?", cex=0.75, adj=c(0,0))
```

[image: Output from example]

Comment: I know you can do the wrapping via `paste(strwrap(longString,width=WIDTH), collapse='\n')`, but I'm not sure how to work out the width (in characters) of the second plot by default in order to calculate the width at which to wrap.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee this may be the simplest solution.  Trade in dynamic calculation of the word wrap point for simplicity (i.e. just choose a `WIDTH` manually based on visual judgement).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `splitTextGrob()` from the R graphics book

```
text = paste(capture.output(licence()),collapse=" ")
library(RGraphics)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(rectGrob(), splitTextGrob(text), ncol=2)

d <- expand.grid(seq(0.1, 0.9, length=10), seq(0.1, 0.9, length=10))
grid.arrange(pointsGrob(d[, 2], d[, 1], pch=21, 
 gp=gpar(fill=rainbow(100))), splitTextGrob(text), ncol=2)
```

[image]

(try resizing the window)

This approach being based on grid graphics, you can either

- use lattice/ggplot2/grid for the plots
- use the `gridBase` package to place base graphics within grid viewports

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  I checked out `gridBase` to use `base` graphics and clearly it is necessary to use `grid.arrange` first and then add the base graphics.  (I need to incorporate `base` because I am plotting objects from `sp` and `raster` package). The vignette associated with the package indicates that this is possible.  I will take a closer read.

Comment: `grid.arrange()` was just a shortcut that I used for illustration; you'll probably want to use `viewport()` instead for a real application with `gridBase`.

Comment: Selecting this as the accepted answer because it solves the problem completely and effectively.  Only downside is that for those unfamiliar with the `grid` graphics system, there is a bit of learning curve.

Comment: How would one increase the top margin of the text?

Answer (score 2):

Some other options to look at (you may want to adapt the code in one of these functions) include the `textplot` function in the `gplots` package and `addtable2plot` in the `plotrix` package.